# How can i remove the "search icon" on this theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I want to remove the search icon/the magnifying glass icon on this theme (broadnews by AF themes).

How will I do it without messing up the others?

I did nothing and was afraid to ruin the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child theme in functions.php add the following line.

```
remove_action('broadnews_load_search_form', 'broadnews_load_search_form_section');
```

Comment: can you be more specific where to add the said code

Comment: In your theme files you should see file called functions.php. We want to use child theme in order to not lose any changes that you apply on our main theme at next update. So the theme author should provide child theme along the main theme. If not you can create your own. After you have the child theme active in the functions.php file add the code. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 0):

You can try it to hide with css:

```
.af-search-wrap {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific where to add the said code

Comment: Navigate to Appearance -> Customize section of your dashboard, scroll down to the bottom of the page and click Additional CSS.